# Can't access to a specfic field in JSON, saying undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5, socket.io-redis

I have a project in Laravel + socket.io , I need to access a specific field in the json being broadcasted. Here is the code.

socket.js

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event,message.data); 
});
```

In my client socket, I have this.

```
socket.on("comment-channel:App\\Events\\CommentEvent", function(message){
        alert(message.data);
 });
```

then this will successfully, alert this.

```
[{
    "id": 136,
    "content": "dffsadf",
    "user_id": "1",
    "task_id": "33",
    "created_at": "2016-03-29 10:47:19",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Hulk",
        "last_name": "Hogan",
        "username": "",
        "email": " hulhogan@yahoo.com",
        "company_id": "1",
        "role_id": "0",
        "photo": "\/assets\/apps\/img\/photos\/lvrv5VOGRskwPHvFVakp.jpeg",
        "position": "asdfsadf",
        "phone": "+75843857834",
        "city": "",
        "country": "Singapore",
        "timezone": "",
        "created_at": "2016-03-10 04:16:24",
        "updated_at": "2016-03-10 07:54:12",
        "deleted_at": null
    }
}]
```

Then when I try this

```
alert(message.data.task_id);
```

or

```
alert(message.data['task_id']);
```

I get 'undefined'..

How can I access, the task_id?Thank You!!!!

Comment: `message.data` is an array

Comment: what type is message.data when you push it from redis to the socket?
the fact that you are able to alert it, already gives away that your data there is not json, but a string?

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, I think you're right, maybe I'll try to pass unparsed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.data` seems to be an array, try `alert(message.data[0].task_id);`

**Edit**: If it doesnt work the problem is not there...

```js
var message = {
 data : [{
   "id" : 136,
   "content" : "dffsadf",
   "user_id" : "1",
   "task_id" : "33",
   "created_at" : "2016-03-29 10:47:19",
   "user" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "first_name" : "Hulk",
    "last_name" : "Hogan",
    "username" : "",
    "email" : " hulhogan@yahoo.com",
    "company_id" : "1",
    "role_id" : "0",
    "photo" : "\/assets\/apps\/img\/photos\/lvrv5VOGRskwPHvFVakp.jpeg",
    "position" : "asdfsadf",
    "phone" : "+75843857834",
    "city" : "",
    "country" : "Singapore",
    "timezone" : "",
    "created_at" : "2016-03-10 04:16:24",
    "updated_at" : "2016-03-10 07:54:12",
    "deleted_at" : null
   }
  }
 ]
};

alert(message.data[0].task_id);
```

**Edit 2** are you sure your `message.data` is not parsed as string ?
try to cast as json object

```js
var message = {
 data : '[{\r\n' + 
'   "id" : 136,\r\n' + 
'   "content" : "dffsadf",\r\n' + 
'   "user_id" : "1",\r\n' + 
'   "task_id" : "33",\r\n' + 
'   "created_at" : "2016-03-29 10:47:19",\r\n' + 
'   "user" : {\r\n' + 
'    "id" : 1,\r\n' + 
'    "first_name" : "Hulk",\r\n' + 
'    "last_name" : "Hogan",\r\n' + 
'    "username" : "",\r\n' + 
'    "email" : " hulhogan@yahoo.com",\r\n' + 
'    "company_id" : "1",\r\n' + 
'    "role_id" : "0",\r\n' + 
'    "photo" : "\/assets\/apps\/img\/photos\/lvrv5VOGRskwPHvFVakp.jpeg",\r\n' + 
'    "position" : "asdfsadf",\r\n' + 
'    "phone" : "+75843857834",\r\n' + 
'    "city" : "",\r\n' + 
'    "country" : "Singapore",\r\n' + 
'    "timezone" : "",\r\n' + 
'    "created_at" : "2016-03-10 04:16:24",\r\n' + 
'    "updated_at" : "2016-03-10 07:54:12",\r\n' + 
'    "deleted_at" : null\r\n' + 
'   }\r\n' + 
'  }\r\n' + 
' ]'
};

var obj = JSON.parse(message.data);
alert(obj[0].task_id);
```

Comment: still saying undefined

Comment: Then when I try alert(message.data[0]);  , it prompts '['

Comment: its because `[` is 0th character of string

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 136,
    "content": "dffsadf",
    "user_id": "1",
    "task_id": "33",
    "created_at": "2016-03-29 10:47:19",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Hulk",
        "last_name": "Hogan",
        "username": "",
        "email": " hulhogan@yahoo.com",
        "company_id": "1",
        "role_id": "0",
        "photo": "\/assets\/apps\/img\/photos\/lvrv5VOGRskwPHvFVakp.jpeg",
        "position": "asdfsadf",
        "phone": "+75843857834",
        "city": "",
        "country": "Singapore",
        "timezone": "",
        "created_at": "2016-03-10 04:16:24",
        "updated_at": "2016-03-10 07:54:12",
        "deleted_at": null
    }
}]
  
  alert(data[0].task_id);
```

This is not an object but array of object you need to access first the object from the array `json[0]` and then you can access any key and value of json.

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment that its prompt `'['` I get to know that its `String` data you need to parse before use.

replace you code from this :

```
 socket.on("comment-channel:App\\Events\\CommentEvent", function(message){
message = JSON.parse(message);
            alert(message.data[0].task_id);
     });
```

Comment: Like this 'alert(message.data[0].task_id);'? , still prompting undefined